# Android Studio 2.1 Emulator Crashes

Tags: android-studio

Here is the error message.

> jdk is up-to-date.

How can I fix it?

Details are below.

```
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 31.496 secs
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at  sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Information:46 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: please someone answer this, I have exactly the same problem. Not even a simple empty project will compile.

Comment: i fix it by changing the API24 to API23   http://i.hizliresim.com/MJ1a19.png   i hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it by changing the API24 to API23

here's the link of screenshot

**i.hizliresim.com/MJ1a19.png**